# Unable to boot from usb onto pcie nvme ssd

Tags: nvme, pcie

I have been trying for days to boot from a usb drive containing the rEFIND bootloader. I had a hard drive with Ubuntu 22.04 on it and cloned it onto an NVME SSD mounted in a PCIEx16 slot.

With the hard drive power removed, when I boot off the USB, it seems to go well but eventually goes into emergency mode with errors:

```
no caching mode page found
assuming drive cache write through
```

I have set up grub as per:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-minimal-bash-like-line-editing-is-supported-grub-error-in-linux/
and I even ran fsck on my SSD partition 1 (EFI) and 6 (Ubuntu).
I cannot decipher the voluminous log from journalctl -xb.
My fdisk -l output is:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048     534527     532480   260M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2     534528     567295      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3     567296 1003449731 1002882436 478.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 1926793216 1928800255    2007040   980M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 1928800256 1953511423   24711168  11.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p6 1003450368 1926793215  923342848 440.3G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sdf: 3.82 GiB, 4103937024 bytes, 8015502 sectors
/dev/sdf1   2048 14878   12831  6.3M EFI System
```

Gparted has a warning about the USB drive:
1007.50 KiB of unallocated space within the partition.
To grow the file system to fill the partition, select the partition and choose the menu item:
Partition --> Check.

When I did the partition check it failed with error message:
Check and repair file system (fat16) on /dev/sdf1  00:00:01    ( ERROR )

```
calibrate /dev/sdf1  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
        
path: /dev/sdf1 (partition)
start: 2048
end: 14878
size: 12831 (6.27 MiB)
check file system on /dev/sdf1 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
        
fsck.fat -a -w -v '/dev/sdf1'  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
        
fsck.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
Checking we can access the last sector of the filesystem
Boot sector contents:
System ID "mkfs.fat"
Media byte 0xf8 (hard disk)
512 bytes per logical sector
2048 bytes per cluster
4 reserved sectors
First FAT starts at byte 2048 (sector 4)
2 FATs, 12 bit entries
4096 bytes per FAT (= 8 sectors)
Root directory starts at byte 10240 (sector 20)
512 root directory entries
Data area starts at byte 26624 (sector 52)
2691 data clusters (5511168 bytes)
32 sectors/track, 2 heads
0 hidden sectors
10816 sectors total
Reclaiming unconnected clusters.
/dev/sdf1: 121 files, 2332/2691 clusters
grow file system to fill the partition  00:00:01    ( ERROR )
        
using libparted
libparted messages    ( ERROR )
        
Could not detect file system.
```

Comment: If sdf not powered, it is not a boot issue. I have used rEFInd for emergency boot, but do not know its details. What brand/model system? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: I have the dmesg output from the boot. It's 1180  lines - too big to attach.

Comment: I was able to successfully boot into the NVME SSD after removing the fstab entry on the root partition of  the ssd for another disconnected hard drive /dev/sdb.